# Accessing global variable in Swift

Tags: swift

Given this sample Swift code:

```
var a = 10;

func foo() -> Int {
    var a = 20;
    return a;
}
```

How can function foo get access to global variable a with value 10 instead of the local a with value 20?

Please note that both a and foo are not declared inside a class but in a generic module. I am looking for a way to tell Swift to access globally defined a var instead of the locally defined one.

Comment: var a and function foo are not declared inside a class but in a module.

Comment: What's the module named?  I think you can do it by calling `Module.a`, but haven't tried it.  https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/3xd560/scoperesolution_operator/

Comment: Also, @Marco, could you edit your question to include the information you provided in the comment?  I think most Swift developers would assume we're working inside a class without any more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a project in Xcode, a console application, the target is here a module.
So I named the project `test` and the target has the same name so in the project the module itself has also the name `test`. Any global definition will be implicit a call to `test.` . Just like the global Swift functions are implicit a call to `Swift.`, like `Swift.print("...")`.

```
var a = 10;

func foo() -> Int {
    let a = 20;
    Swift.print(test.a) // same as print(test.a)

    return a;
}

test.foo() // same as foo()
```

Output is:

> 10

---

So you have to add the module name before the variable to get the global one and not the local one overshadowing it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `self` keyword:

```
func foo() -> Int {
    var a = 20;
    return self.a;
}
```

Comment: foo is not a method defined into a class, it is a function, so self is not available.

Comment: What if var a = 10; is not inside the same class? You'll get no member error.

Answer (score 2):

```
 func foo(bar:Any) -> Int {
        let a = 20
        if bar is Bar {
            let c = bar as? Bar
            return c!.a
        }
        return a
  }
```

Comment: You should do `if let c = bar as? Bar` instead of force casting.